# Identifying outliers in the data

Tags: spss

I have a program that removes data that are outliers. In the data set, an outlier is a value that is more than 2 standard deviations greater than or less than the mean. Is there a way to record/store which data points were considered outliers so we can look at them later?

Comment: The program that removes the cases is in SPSS syntax? It should be easy enough to edit it and add a command to save those cases to a separate file. Can you add the syntax to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the cases where a value is more than 2 std's distant than the mean you can do this:

```
aggregate 
    /out=* mode=addvariables /break= /yourvrS=SD(yourvr) /yourvrM=mean(yourvr).
compute outlier = abs(yourvr - yourvrM) > 2 * yourvrS .
```

The new variable`outlier` will receive the value `1` for outlier values.